# Pass Values from Form -> Class -> Form C#

Tags: c#

I have *2 Forms*: **V.Batch** and **V.BatchEdit** and a *Class*: **M.Batch**

In *V.Batch* there is a DataGrid. I want to pass the value I get from the DataGrid to *V.BatchEdit* and the get set method is in *M.Batch*.

The problem here is that the value isn't passed properly in *V.BatchEdit*. It returns 0.

Here is the code

### V.Batch:

```
M.Batch bt;
public Batch()
    {
        bt = new M.Batch();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

 private void metroButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bt.batchNum = Convert.ToInt32((metroGrid2.CurrentCell.Value).ToString());
        V.BatchEdit bEdit = new V.BatchEdit();
        this.Hide(); 
        bEdit.Show();

    }
```

### M.Batch:

```
public int batchNum;

public int BatchNum
    {
        set { batchNum = value; }
        get { return batchNum; }
    }
```

### V.BatchEdit

```
 static M.Batch bt = new M.Batch();
 DataSet a = bt.getBatch(bt.batchNum);
public BatchEdit()
    {
        db = new Database();
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(bt.batchNum.ToString() + "Batchedit");
        try
        {

            metroTextBox1.Text = a.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I'm new to coding and c#. I'm not sure if I placed static even though it should not be static or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are using `static` improperly here.

The easiest way to see what's going wrong is to notice that you are calling `new M.Batch()` twice. That means you have two different instances of `M.Batch` in your application. And nowhere in your code do you attempt to share those instances.

What you should be doing is passing your instance of `M.Batch` from one form to another, e.g. in the constructor:

```
// V.Batch
bt.batchNum = Convert.ToInt32((metroGrid2.CurrentCell.Value).ToString());
V.BatchEdit bEdit = new V.BatchEdit(bt);
this.Hide(); 
bEdit.Show();

// V.BatchEdit
private M.Batch bt;
private DataSet a;

public BatchEdit(M.Batch batch)
{
  this.bt = batch;
  this.a = this.bt.getBatch(bt.batchNum)

  // Rest of your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You don't need the 'M.Batch' class for something else and you only use it for passing the value to V.BaychEdit, just declare a public property in V.BatchEdit like you did in M.Batch and use it like this:

```
V.BatchEdit bEdit = new V.BatchEdit();
bEdit.BatchNum = Convert.ToInt32((metroGrid2.CurrentCell.Value).ToString());
```

Your problem is that although your using statics you're still assigning a new instance to the static field.

Comment: I'm using it as a "model". I have SQL statements in M.Batch aside from the get set methods :) but will try your suggestion